# CUDA install removes Nvidia driver in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

After installing CUDA 11, It removed my Nvidia driver.

```
$nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0

$uname -r
5.4.0-47-generic
```

It doesn’t allow me to select Nvidia from the software & updates center. Why is that?
[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paO8I.png)

Should I install my Nvidia driver manually? Because previously I had an issue with the black screen after installing manually the Nvidia driver. I need your suggestion. What should I do?

Looks like, CUDA 11 is incompatible with `Nvidia 340.108`, and that’s why when I install CUDA, It installed `nvidia-driver-450` and removed `nvidia 340.108`.

```
Tue Sep 22 11:52:40 2020       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.108    Driver Version: 340.108        |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 820M        Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    212MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Which Cuda toolkit is compatible with the above driver?

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001140sv000017AAsd0000380Dbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (GeForce 820M)
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

After installing `nvidia-driver-450`

```
dmesg |grep -i nvidia
[   17.274190] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   17.274202] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   17.283429] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   17.292951] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[   17.293403] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 450.66 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   17.293404] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   17.293527] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
[   17.372253] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[   17.372708] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 450.66 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   17.372710] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   17.372844] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
[   43.172017] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[   43.173631] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 450.66 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   43.173633] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   43.173822] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
pranto@pranto-Lenovo-Z40-70:~$ lsmod | grep nvidia
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256378/question-about-installing-cuda-10-1-on-ubuntu-20-04-the-root-folder-is-empty/1256583#1256583 for an install method to avoid package manager entanglement with cuda and Nvidia packages.

Comment: `driver: nvidia-340 - distro non-free` and `driver: nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free recommended` which one should I install? Because `nvidia-smi` failed when I install `nvidia-driver-450`

Comment: @ubfan1, Which CUDA version should I choose for `Nvidia - 340.108`? Because CUDA 11 is incompatible with `Nvidia - 340.108` and while installing CUDA 11, It installed `nvidia-driver-450`

Comment: I can't speak to CUDA11, but I have a 20.04  CUDA 10.2 with the 450 driver, and 10.1 with the 440 driver. nvidia-smi works for both. Probably you have a version mismatch somewhere. I would think the 450 driver should be the one to use (says "proprietary tested" in the Additional Drivers list). I think the 450 driver is just working through the standard repos now -- I hadn't noticed it on my systems before yesterday, I'd been using 440.

Comment: @ubfan1 I installed `nvidia-driver-450` but `nvidia-smi` doesn't work with that, said `didn't find NVIDIA driver`. You are right `nvidia-450` in the additional driver list, It says "proprietary tested" but doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Try a reboot, then dmesg |grep -i nvidia to see if the 450.66 kernel module got loaded. Does lsmod have "nvidia" in its module list?  Sometimes older driver files get leftover and cause problems.

Comment: @ubfan1 It only works with `nvidia 340.108`. Thoughts @ubfan1?

Comment: This time I install `nvidia-driver-390` and It's working. `Driver Version: 390.138`. But `nvidia-driver-450` still recommended. Why is that?

Comment: nvidia-smi comes in the nvidia-utils-xxx packages, so  maybe the one that doesn't run with 450 is an old copy.  I ran an older quadro 1000m on the 435 driver, but was limited to CUDA8.0  by the 2.1 compute capability. Had to get an expresscard/pci adapter to run a GTX970 before I could get Tensorflow running on the 440 driver (now 450).

Comment: Now, which CUDA toolkit is compatible with `nvidia-390.138`? 9.1? @ubfan1

Comment: `nvidia-smi comes in the nvidia-utils-xxx packages, so maybe the one that doesn't run with 450 is an old copy.` >> What's the solution in my case?

Comment: If you install the nvidia-driver-450, also install the nvidia-utils-450. Although I'd think the utils should be brought in as a dependency, depends upon how you installed the driver originally.sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450 should get all that's needed, I just did that on my system running the 440 driver and updated to the 450 driver.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450` didn't work in my case. `[ 17.372708]   NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M GPU installed in this system is
 supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please
 visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information. The 450.66 NVIDIA driver will ignore`

Comment: From Nvidia official web, It shows for NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M `version: 430.40` is possible to download but why ubuntu recommend me to install `nvidia-450`?

Comment: Ubuntu does have the 430 driver packages in the standard repos.  Did you try 430?  At some point, Nvidia drops support for legacy cards, but sometimes they still work -- though  not apparently for your card. Your card "compute capability" of 2.1 may be another problem -- my 2.1 cap card would only install/run up to CUDA 8.0

Comment: @ubfan1 I did but again it installed `nvidia-driver-450`